# What are the different parts of the heap specified in the hs_err_pid file?

Tags: java, gcc, jvm

Below is a part of the `hs_err_pid`

```
Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 13888K, used 9807K [0x8a330000, 0x8b140000, 0x914f0000)
  eden space 13504K, 69% used [0x8a330000,0x8ac67710,0x8b060000)
  from space 384K, 96% used [0x8b0e0000,0x8b13c6e0,0x8b140000)
  to   space 448K, 0% used [0x8b060000,0x8b060000,0x8b0d0000)
 PSOldGen        total 115456K, used 57684K [0x514f0000, 0x585b0000, 0x8a330000)
  object space 115456K, 49% used [0x514f0000,0x54d451c0,0x585b0000)
 PSPermGen       total 16384K, used 11253K [0x4d4f0000, 0x4e4f0000, 0x514f0000)
  object space 16384K, 68% used [0x4d4f0000,0x4dfed618,0x4e4f0000)
```

What are

1. PSYoungGen
2. eden space (from space, to space)
3. PSOldGen
4. PSPermGen (object space)

Answer (score 5):

**Heap memory is organized into different *generations*.**

[image: Default Arrangement of Generations, Except for Parallel Collector and G1]

**1. Young Generation** : Mostly all new objects are created in Young Generation initially. This generation is divided into two areas, namely **Eden space** and 
**Survivor space**. Survivor space is further divided into two areas **Survivor0** and **Survivor1**. All new Objects are initially created in Eden Space and survivor spaces are mainly used while having minor garbage collection.

Before every minor collection one Survivor space will be empty (`to`) and this will used to keep the *live* objects from `eden` space or `from` survivor space for minor collections.

[image: Young Generation Minor Collection 1]

For next minor collection it will be vice versa, i.e former `from` will be `to` and `to` will be `form`.

[image: Young Generation Minor Collection 2]

**2. Tenured or Old Generation** : Objects  that `lives` in the Young Generation for some time (i.e *survived a few minor collections*) are moved to Old generation.

**3. Permanent Generation** : This area mainly contains class and methods metadata. [Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279449/what-is-perm-space).

---

```
    Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 13888K, used 9807K [0x8a330000, 0x8b140000, 0x914f0000)
  eden space 13504K, 69% used [0x8a330000,0x8ac67710,0x8b060000)
  from space 384K, 96% used [0x8b0e0000,0x8b13c6e0,0x8b140000)
  to   space 448K, 0% used [0x8b060000,0x8b060000,0x8b0d0000)
 PSOldGen        total 115456K, used 57684K [0x514f0000, 0x585b0000, 0x8a330000)
  object space 115456K, 49% used [0x514f0000,0x54d451c0,0x585b0000)
 PSPermGen       total 16384K, used 11253K [0x4d4f0000, 0x4e4f0000, 0x514f0000)
  object space 16384K, 68% used [0x4d4f0000,0x4dfed618,0x4e4f0000)
```

The above is showing the memory usage summary of the different generations in Heap.

*Please [read this Sun white paper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memorymanagement-whitepaper-150215.pdf) for a clear understanding.*

Answer (score 4):

These are the memory regions used by the garbage collector.

See the [memory management whitepaper from Sun](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memorymanagement-whitepaper-150215.pdf) (PDF) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

This is your [Java HotSpot Garbage Collection](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/hotspot/gc/index.jsp) source of information.

> HotSpot Generations
>
> Memory in the Java
>   HotSpot virtual machine is organized
>   into three generations: a young
>   generation, an old generation, and a
>   permanent generation. Most objects are
>   initially allocated in the young
>   generation. The old generation
>   contains objects that have survived
>   some number of young generation
>   collections, as well as some large
>   objects that may be allocated directly
>   in the old generation. The permanent
>   generation holds objects that the JVM
>   finds convenient to have the garbage
>   collector manage, such as objects
>   describing classes and methods, as
>   well as the classes and methods
>   themselves.