# Is a static class kept or disposed after using StaticClass.staticValue

Tags: java, memory-leaks, static-class

Is a static class kept along with it’s static variables in the memory after using it once, or is it instantiated along with every variable every time I use it?

To make it more real lets create an example.
Let’s say I want to make a language dictionary for my system not using singletons.
My static language class with 2 static variables:

```
package server;  
import java.util.Locale;  
import java.util.ResourceBundle;  

public abstract class Language {  
    private static Locale language = new Locale("en", "GB");  
    public static ResourceBundle dictionary = ResourceBundle.getBundle("dictionary_"+Language.language, Language.language);  

    public static void changeLanguage(Locale language){  
        Language.language = language;  
        Language.dictionary = ResourceBundle.getBundle("dictionary_"+Language.language, Language.language);  
    }  
}
```

When I use it in the system to get a tekst value like so:

```
System.out.println(Language.dictionary.getString("system.name"));
```

Will the whole class along with dictionary static variable stay in memory until I use it again, or will it be created again, and again eating my memory every time I do so?

Comment: Classes are loaded once and for all at JVM startup; they are not reloaded a second time. `static final` variables are the same. (unrelated: have a look at [this project](https://github.com/fge/msg-simple), it may help you)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually Static variables stored in a specific space in the memory called `PermGen`, this area holds you static variables once you used them. and if you want to use it again it will get them from that space with out re-creating them again.

But this space could get filled during the execution time, here the `GC` will start collect and delete some references from it, in this case if your variable got delete by `GC` and you want to use it again it will be created again.

You can read more about [PermGen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279449/what-is-perm-space)

Comment: "PermGen", not "PerGen" ;)