# running grails application in Geronimo

Tags: grails, geronimo

I am running into issues where by my grails web-app is unable to start in geronimo.
These are the version I am running with
- Grails version 1.3.7
- Geronimo version 2.1.1
whatever I do application fails to start with varied exceptions mostly tied to perm-gen errors

Some of the exceptions I end up getting are

```
09:43:27,733 ERROR [ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory] Destroy method on bean with name 'eventTriggeringInterceptor' threw an exception
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.classloader.JarFileClassLoader.access$200(JarFileClassLoader.java:52)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.classloader.JarFileClassLoader$6.run(JarFileClassLoader.java:308)
```

I really need some help here, I am stuck what to do next or how to resolve.
I used

```
set JAVA_OPTS= -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m in geronimo.bat
```

but that didn't help either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing the options to

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-verbose:gc -Xmx756m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

did the trick for me.

Comment: I'm confused, so you didn't increase the perm gen at all, just set the garbage collection output to verbose? How did that fix anything?

Comment: No I changed the max heap i.e. reduced from 1GB to 756M.
Since OOM error was from PermGen space and not really heap memory.
Reducing heap to 756 allowed more process memory to be available for native heap. 
Look at this SO for details regarding PermGen
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279449/what-is-perm-space