# Regarding immutable List (created by Arrays.asList())

Tags: java, arrays, list, collections, immutablelist

When we create a list from an array using `java.util.Arrays.asList()`, the list is immutable. I am just curious to know why do we want to create a immutable list when the basic purpose of `List` (or `Set` or `Map`) is to have dynamic size and to be able to add, remove elements at will. When we need a fixed size data structure we go for Array and when we need a dynamic data structure we go for `List` or `Set` or `Map` etc. So what is the purpose of having a immutable list? I came across this while working on my assignment.

Comment: By mutable, you mean immutable?

Comment: What do you mean by "in this case"? Generally I find your question hard to understand. You seem to mix up concepts of Arrays and Lists.

Comment: Sorry for mistakes in my question.corrected them now.Please check.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> When we create a list from an array using java.util.Arrays.asList() , the list is mutable.

Yes and no: The list may be modified, by calling

```
list.set(index, element);
```

But the list may **not** be *structurally* modified. That means that it is not possible to add elements to the list or remove elements from the list. The reason simply is that the list is still backed by the array, and the size of the array may not change.

> When we need a fixed size mutable collection we go for Array

And that's the key point here: An array is **not** a [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html). The `Arrays.asList` method mainly serves as a "bridge" between the "arrays world" and the "collections world".

The `Arrays.asList` method allows you, for example, the pass data to a method that expects a `Collection`:

```
// A method that expects a collection:
void process(List<String> strings) { ... }

void call()
{
    String array[] = new String[] { "A", "B", "C" };

    // Pass the array (as a list) to the method:
    process(Arrays.asList(array));
}
```

This application case includes creating other collections from an array. For example, if you have an array and want to create a `Set` containing the elements from the array, you could to

```
String array[] = new String[] { "A", "B", "C" };
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
for (String s : array) 
{
    set.add(s);
}
```

But with the `Arrays.asList` method, this can be done more conveniently:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
```

The `Arrays.asList` method is so to say the counterpart of the [Collection#toArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray-T:A-) method, which works in the opposite direction (although this method usually involves creating and filling a *new* array, whereas the `Arrays.asList` method just "wraps" an array and lets it "look like" a `List`).

Comment: I agree that asList method serves as bridge between Arrays world and Collections world.I also agree that there are ways to create a mutable list from an Array.But I don't understand clearly why a list ceated by asList is immutable? What is the main purpose of making it immutable ?

Comment: @Venkat I already said that its elements may be modified, but not the size of the list. And the reason for that is that the `List` interface is implemented so that the actual *data* is still stored in the array. And in Java, the size of an array can not change. If you want to create a mutable list from an array, you can use `new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array));`. So they did "not intentionally" make the list structurally immutable. It is only a side-effect of the fact that the list is backed by an array.

Comment: `public E set(int index, E element) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }`

Comment: Having the API provide an "add" method and disabling that method by means of throwing UnsupportedOperationException seems like a very very bad idea...

Answer (score 4):

`java.util.Arrays.asList()` calls `return new ArrayList<>(a);` but this ArrayList is a private class of Arrays which extends `AbstractList` and override some implementation. So, it's unfair to expect a behavior of `java.util.ArrayList`. If you look into `java.util.AbstractList` you will see that you can call add(E e) but not many other methods. So, as per the current implementation, you can add an element at the bottom of the list but can't change the existing structure of the list.

Comment: Always thought the `ArrayList` returned is the `java.util.ArrayList`. Never knew it was a completely different class.

Answer (score 2):

If you call `System.out.println(Arrays.asList("a", "b").getClass());`

the runtime type is `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList`,

but if you call `System.out.println(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b").getClass()));`

the runtime type is `java.util.ArrayList`.

Maybe this distinction helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of `add()` in class **AbstractList**, extended by the customised ArrayList (inner static class) under Arrays java class(that is used internally). Please note this add() method is not the same defined in java.util.ArrayList but is that of `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList`.

An array has the property of being fixed size, provided natively by jvm. Even if, Arrays.copyOf() is used with increased size such as `Arrays.copyOf(arr, 10); //10 is the length`, where the original array is `arr= int[]{1,2} // size is two`. It creates *always a new array* using `System.arraycopy()` which eventually calls a **native method**.

[static void arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)]

Please note, the above list has size restrictions only, if you really want to make a mutable list immutable, please try using `Collections.unmodifiableList(mutableList);` 
Immutablility is not a jvm defined concept but is a developer thought. please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42071121/5620851 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/42138471/5620851